# Exclude one field from Nhb dirty optimistic locking

Tags: c#, nhibernate

We setup our entity updates with dirty optimistic locking in Nhb configuration:

```
.Override<OurEntity>(x =>
{
    x.DynamicUpdate();
    x.OptimisticLock.Dirty();
...
}
```

It generates requests that update only actually changed fields with WHERE statement insuring that no one thread got this fields updated in parallel resulting in queries like `UPDATE OurEntity SET f1 = 'new value' WHERE f1 = 'old value'`.

However what if now we need to exclude one single field from optimistic locking leaving it work as is for dozens of others? so that WHERE statement does not include this field in the query, as we do not care how many threads and how often update this particular field in parallel.

Is it possible to do? If not with optimistic locking, any suggestions on workarounds? Thanks

One of workaround would be to move the field to a separate table but we'd like to avoid this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add .Not.OptimisticLock() on the field you want to ignore from the optimistic lock check:

```
.Override<OurEntity>(x =>
{
    x.DynamicUpdate();
    x.OptimisticLock.Dirty();
    x.Map(f => f.FieldToExclude).Not.OptimisticLock();
    ...
}
```

It works also on References:

```
References(f => f.ReferencedObject).Not.OptimisticLock();
```